# AJAX on scroll reloads page within div in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So essentially I'm able to get WP and AJAX to load a page whenever I've got a 'click' event in JQuery. With the click event it works properly, however, when switching it all to function on scroll, instead of properly reloading the following post or posts (as it does when you click) it instead reloads the entire page of the site within the designated div.

Here's my code:

**Ajax.php**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_art_load_single','art_load_single');
add_action('wp_ajax_art_load_single','art_load_single');

function art_load_single(){

    $paged = $_POST["page"]+1;

    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    ));

    ?>


    <?php if($query->have_posts()):
        while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>

         <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <header class="entry-header">
            <div class="entry-title">
              <?php the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' ); ?>
                <h2 class="sub-headline">
                    <?php if ( ! has_excerpt() ) {
                        echo '';
                    } else { 
                        the_excerpt();
                    }   ?>        
                </h2>
            </div>

                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                    <div class="article-featured-image">
                        <a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" rel="lightbox" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></a>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php
                    wp_link_pages( array(
                        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'some_theme' ),
                        'after'  => '</div>',
                    ) );
                ?>



            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
         </article><!-- #post-## -->

     <?php endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


    <?php die();

}
```

**Load-more.js**

```
var postContainer = document.getElementById('primary');
var request_in_progress = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    infiniteScroll();
});

function infiniteScroll(){
    var content_height = postContainer.offsetHeight;
    var current_y = window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset;
    if(current_y >= content_height) 
        showSinglePost();
    } 
}

//$(document).on('click','.load-single-article', function(){
function showSinglePost(){

    if(request_in_progress) { return; }
    request_in_progress = true;

    var that = $(this);
    var page = that.data('page');
    var newPage = page+1;
    var ajaxurl = that.data('url');

    that.find('.text').html('LOADING...');

    $.ajax({

        url : ajaxurl,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            page : page,
            action : 'art_load_single',
            dataType: 'post'
        },
        error : function( response ){
            console.log(response);
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            setTimeout(function(){

                that.data('page', newPage);
                $('#primary').append( response );

                that.find('.text').html('VIEW MORE');

                request_in_progress = false;

            }, 500);

        }

    });
}
```

Leaving in the 'click' event just in case. Finally my button for clicking is below:

```
<a class="view-btn load-single-article" data-page="1" data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>"><span class="text">VIEW MORE</span></a>
```

Being slightly new to AJAX I believe it could just be the URL reacts differently when called on click vs when loading on scroll, or maybe the click is just working as a fluke. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: With the click event handler you've got the `data-` attributes, telling the script what page to load and where to get it.  When you use the scroll event you don't have that at all.  You may need to rethink the way you've approached this, but you obviously have everything you need so far

Comment: Thanks, Archer. So to make sure I understand what you're saying, I need to recreate the button to use something like data-id as opposed to data-page, and redo some of my AJAX to handle that correct?

Comment: The fact that you're trying to swap click events for scroll events really makes this a confusing question.  If you just load more pages when you scroll then you'll load pages when you scroll down, and then load more when you scroll back up.  It just doesn't sound friendly (or useful).

Comment: Hey Archer, something _like_ that, but instead of 'clicking' the load more button, ideally the site would start to load posts as you scroll down. Something like this (but WP instead of Tumblr): https://www.tumblr.com/search/resource:%20infinite%20scrolling

Comment: Okay, I know what you're after - I'll post some code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a stripped back version of what you want, so you should be able to just plug in your own article loading etc..  It starts off with a bunch of articles already loaded and when you scroll it checks to see where one the page you are.  If you're at the bottom of the page then it loads a new article and appends it.

```js
var articleCount = 0;
var $window = $(window);
var $body = $("body");

$window.on("scroll", function() {
    // check to see if we're near the bottom of the page
    if ($window.scrollTop() > $body.height() - $window.innerHeight()) {
        // we are at the bottom, so load a new article
        loadNextArticle();
  }
});

// make this function actually load an article and append it to the page
function loadNextArticle() {
    articleCount++;
    $body.append("<div class=\"single-article\">I am article number " + articleCount + "</div>");
}

// create some articles when the page loads...
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    loadNextArticle();
}
```

```css
.single-article {
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 240);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously you'll need to amend this to suit your specific requirements, but I've tried to make it as generic as possible.  Realistically you should just be able to copy/paste the Javascript into your site and swap out the part that loads and appends a new article.